# iText - PdfPTable RowSpan using mytable.writeSelectedRows

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText 5.1.3, and I want to add a header to my Pdf Document. I used the known solution posted here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104

This solution used the `PdfPageEventHelper` class, and overridden the method `onEndPage()` to add the Header exactly after finishing every page. The example provided in the link above works fine as it adds a table as the Header of the document. I'm trying to do exactly the same with 1 difference, that I want some cells in that table to have Rowspan and/or Colspan.

I tried, and found that using `table.writeSelectedRows()` differs from `document.add(table)` when it comes to `Rowspan`. This is a sample of what I'm trying to do in `onEndPage`:

```
PdfPTable mytable = new PdfPTable(3);
mytable.setTotalWidth(527);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello"));
cell1.setColspan(2);
cell1.setRowspan(2);
mytable.addCell(cell1);

PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Girls !"));
mytable.addCell(cell2);

PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Boys !"));
mytable.addCell(cell3);

mytable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
```

and instead of having a cell at the left as 2x2 with "Hello", I get the "Hello" cell as 1x2 not 2x2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well .. I found the solution myself :D It's simply replacing `mytable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());` with the following:

```
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
column.addElement(mytable);
column.setSimpleColumn(-12, -20, 604, 803); // set LLx, LLy, URx, and URy of the header
column.go();
```

That's it :) worked :)

Answer (score 0):

iText writeSelectedRows not work with rowSpan when I use iText-2.1.7, The rowSpan cell not grow to other rows,But it has a workaround.

```
ArrayList tmp = table.getRows(0, table.getRows().size());
table.getRows().clear();
table.getRows().addAll(tmp);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, directContent);
```